# Modulo arithmetic, specifically n! mod m

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

Is there a theorem that makes solving 
$$
n! \equiv x     \mod m
$$
knowing that both $n$ and $m$ are prime?

And if not, what would be the best way to go about finding $x$?

cheers

Comment: Are you raising the problem from a computational efficient standpoint or from a math standpoint? If it is from the math standpoint, then the response is straightforward: $x$ is the remainder of the euclidean division of $n!$ by $m$

Comment: I understand that it is fairly straight forward to find $x$ computationally, like using a loop and reducing the number modularly. However I'm looking for a faster way to do it by hand, a smarter way perhaps, to find $x$, the remainder of dividing $n!$ by $m$.
PS: $x$ is unknown.

Comment: Well one obvious fact is that $n>m$ implies the reduction is 0. So the question is what happens with $n<m$ and $n!>m$.

Comment: Yes, if $n>m$ then $n!$ will be a multiple of $m$, you're quite right

Comment: Also notice that $m$ is prime, so reducing the problem by dividing by $gcd(n!, m)$ is not an option

Comment: I have found a theorem that states:
If $p$ is prime then $(p -1) \equiv -1 \mod p$.
maybe this helps

Comment: That ($(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p$) is [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) - for $p$ prime (but therefore $p-1$ is no prime except for $p=3$ which yields the trivial $2!\equiv 2\mod3$...)